# I want to create label in gmail using google-api but i get error Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

My client_id, secret_id, developer_key and redirect_uri for auth request is set in config file which is included.
I use following code for create label in gmail account using google-api-php-client :-

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // set include path for google php client library
    set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'google-api-php-client-master/src' );
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();

    // call when redirect after callback by google oauth
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
    {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
        {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        }

        $data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                   <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
                     <apps:property name="label" value="TestCreatedByApi" />
                   </atom:entry>';

        $headers = array(
              "X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST",
              "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
              "Content-type: application/atom+xml"
        );


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/google.com/{username}/label");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        print_r($response = curl_exec($ch));

   }

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
$client->addScope("https://mail.google.com");

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

?>
```

This is view section of code:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="request">
    <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
      <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <form id="url" method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input name="url" class="url" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Shorten">
      </form>
      <a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>
    <?php endif ?>
  </div>

  <?php if (isset($short)): ?>
    <div class="shortened">
      <?php var_dump($short); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

I use for add scope to create label:

```
 $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
 $client->addScope("https://mail.google.com");
```

I get following error:

```
Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
Error 401
```

Answer (score 1):

The right scope for creating a email label is

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/

check out documentation here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/auth

and also here:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_labels

Comment: After adding https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/ in scope i get following response :-

HTTP/1.1 403 Invalid domain.
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 10:20:13 GMT
Expires: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 10:20:13 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Invalid domain.

Error 403

For more detail please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670433/invalid-domain-error-in-gmail-setting-api

Comment: Are you actually trying to access labels on your gmail.com account? If so, that's not supposed to work as the Email Settings API works only on Premier and Edu Google Apps domains.