# Invalid domain error in gmail setting api

Tags: google-api

I want to create a label in gmail account using goggle admin sdk api.

I am sending a Http Post Request to

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{domain}/{username}/label/

**But i get this response :-**

```
Invalid domain.

Error 403
```

**Following is the code for this task :-**

```
 $domain = explode('@',$user->email);
 $headers = array(
  "X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST",
  "Authorization: {$obj->token_type} "." {$obj->access_token}",
  "Content-type: application/atom+xml",
  );

   $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/$domain[1]/$domain[0]/label",
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                 // CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
                 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                 // CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
                 // CURLOPT_POST => true
                  );

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually trying to access labels on your gmail.com account from your domain's admin account, it will not work.  The email setting API works only on Premier and Edu Google Apps domains administrators.

Comment: My account is business account.
I want to ask this should be admin account or not ?

Comment: Thanks,
I am able to create label in the account of user in same domain.
But it doesn't work in other domain like gmail.com . 
is there any way to create label in gmail.com or other domain ?

zendesk.com configure gmail account and can create label for any domain. I want to implement same functionality. Please help me.

Comment: So I can't speak for how zendesk works since I have no insights... but it really depends on how you want to authenticate right.  The Email setting API allows administrator to change labels for users in the administrator domain.  However, if you are authenticated/impersonated as the user, then yes you can grant access to the application to change your labels via the APIs.  You can do that via service account for other Google Apps domains.  The other way to do that is to implement 3LO and ask the user's for permission.

Comment: I am trying 3LO but i get error. You can see my code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755020/getting-error-authorized-token-from-service-provider-does-not-match-supplied-re